I'm creating next.js App with mongodb. but app/api/ 404 not found in vercel
I really need your support.
I'm creating next.js app with mongodb and deployed to vercel.
but not working app/api/ to get the data of mongodb.
https://vercel.app/api/ is displayed 404 not found...
other page working.
only app/api not working.
this is my code↓
app/api/user/route.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { connectDb } from "@/utils/database";
import { UserModel } from "@/models/userModel";

export const GET = async (request: NextRequest) => {
  try {
    await connectDb();

    const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
    const name = searchParams.get("name");

    if (!name) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { message: "400" },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ name });

    if (user) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        message: "successful",
        user: user,
      });
    } else {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { message: "404" },
        { status: 404 }
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "500 },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
};


utils/database.ts

import mongoose from "mongoose";

export const connectDb = async () => {
  try {
    const url = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
    if (!url) {
      throw new Error();
    }
    await mongoose.connect(url);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error();
  }
};


models/userModel.ts
import { PortOfSpeech } from "@/types/types";
import mongoose, { Document, Schema } from "mongoose";

export interface WordData {
  word_id: string;
  word: string;
  wordMeaning: string;
  sentence: string;
  sentenceMeaning: string;
  portOfSpeech: PortOfSpeech[];
  isCompleted: boolean;
}

export interface User {
  name: string;
  password: string;
  level600_data: WordData[];
  level730_data: WordData[];
  level860_data: WordData[];
  level990_data: WordData[];
}

export interface UserDocument extends User, Document {
  _id: string;
}

const userSchema = new Schema<UserDocument>(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    level600_data: {
      type: [
        {
          word_id: String,
          word: String,
          wordMeaning: String,
          sentence: String,
          sentenceMeaning: String,
          portOfSpeech: [String],
          isCompleted: Boolean,
        },
      ],
      default: [],
    },
    level730_data: {
      type: [
        {
          word_id: String,
          word: String,
          wordMeaning: String,
          sentence: String,
          sentenceMeaning: String,
          portOfSpeech: [String],
          isCompleted: Boolean,
        },
      ],
      default: [],
    },
    level860_data: {
      type: [
        {
          word_id: String,
          word: String,
          wordMeaning: String,
          sentence: String,
          sentenceMeaning: String,
          portOfSpeech: [String],
          isCompleted: Boolean,
        },
      ],
      default: [],
    },
    level990_data: {
      type: [
        {
          word_id: String,
          word: String,
          wordMeaning: String,
          sentence: String,
          sentenceMeaning: String,
          portOfSpeech: [String],
          isCompleted: Boolean,
        },
      ],
      default: [],
    },
  },
  { collection: "user_data" }
);

export const UserModel =
  mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model<UserDocument>("User", userSchema);


.env
MONGODB_URI=my mongodb uri

NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://localhost:3000/api

Environment Variables　is set to vercel.↓
enter image description here
but not working.....
enter image description here
enter image description here
I don't know how to resolve it...
Could you tell me how to fix it....

Welcome to stackoverflow, i don't quite understand what you mean by "but not working app/api/ to get the data of mongodb", but i suppose you are trying to fetch the endpoint, if you want to fetch users you will have to provide the whole route /api/user in your fetch function, if this is not what you mean, maybe you can edit the post to provide the component where you are fetching  the data from.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
